# append json objects to file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I simply want to write a json object into a file (not necessarily a .json file) after calling a certain function. When calling that function with another json object, I want to append that object to the file.

Currently I am using [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) for that.

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
...
users_file = "./users_file";
function update(user_json) {
    jsonfile.writeFile(users_file,user_json), function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

But calling update again with another json object, the first line will be overwritten.

example:

```
json1 = {"id":123456,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","username":"johnsmith"}
json2 = {"id":654321,"first_name":"marc","last_name":"cold","username":"marccold"}
```

when calling `update(json1)` and later `update(json2)` I want the file to look like this:

```
{"id":123456,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","username":"johnsmith"}
{"id":654321,"first_name":"marc","last_name":"cold","username":"marccold"}
```

Currently the second line is replacing the first line. I tried to read the file first and then concat both json objects but that failed. Also that needs to work when the file is empty.

Comment: try using the function appendFile() instead of writeFile()

Comment: thanks. You can add this as an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use appendFile() instead of writeFile(). writeFile() is to write a new file or overwrite existing file if any. While appendFile() is to append Content to the existing file if any or create a new file and add the content.